# problem getting my domain redirect to update .html files in dropbox after used iweb SEO TOOL

Tags: redirect, seo, dropbox, iweb

So I created a nice 6 page website hutchspropertyandtree.co.nr using freedomain.co.nr via dropbox public folder.  Everything was working and updating properly until i updated with iwebs SEO TOOL.  I added meta and title tags as well as description etc...  PROBLEM is that even though my .html files in dropbox are correct and show all new code and tags.  when i open up my domain hutchspropertyandtree.co.nr it doesnt show any of my recent seo tool updates.

im thinking that the cheap domainname from .co.nr is the problem?  Is it possible that the default tags and titles and keywords entered into the co.nr website creation boxs are overwriting the newer ones in the html within my dropbox?

But still doesnt explain why a stat counter code and google analytics code in the footer and header respectively still do not show up when i view source in browser.

PLEASE PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the page at `hutchspropertyandtree.co.nr` uses a frame to show the content from another location. The meta information comes from the page with the frame, not the page in the frame. You should be able to see the content of the frame using an inspector (comes with all browsers these days) or "View frame source", if your browser does that.

Note that any search engine hits to your pages will link to the dropbox URL, not the frame page (that has essentially no content from the viewpoint of a search engine). If you want search engine results to show up under that domain, you'll have to get hosting that lets you point a domain directly to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! So are you saying that in order to have my iweb seo tool's updates to properly show i need a new host?  I can't use .co.nr or .tk free hosting?

Comment: In trying to make an xml sitemap.  All generators do not return more than one page for hutchspropertyandtree.co.nr.  However if i run http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26720633/Hutchs_Property_and_Tree/Home.html (the web location) in a generator it works great.  IS there anyway i can keep my free domain (its much nicer for customers than the drop box site) and have the redirected domain page return positive results from the generator?  I'm guessing this has to do with the frames.  Any way around this problem?  Thanks so much for any help

Comment: Bottom line is, get rid of the frame. It's more trouble than its worth. You might have to pay for hosting, but if you only have one domain with a few static pages, it's going to be ridiculously cheap.

Comment: Im sorry, im pretty new to this.  So does the framing stem from my dropbox host or my .co.nr domain?  So your saying then if i buy a legit domain and keep dropbox as my host (our should i used to the purchased domain hosting) it will remove frame issue and my updated seo tags will work and xlm generator and google bot will finally work?